# Глюк с вводом данных от пользователя

Tags: python, if

У меня есть код, который генерирует случайные математические примеры. Программа спрашивает у пользователя, какой он хочет знак в примере `(+, -, /, *)`. И дальше условие на то, написал ли он вообще матем. оператор, а не какой-либо `"йсмйСЙ234ВЙ2Ф"`. Я тестировал, и заметил: когда я пишу именно матем. оператор, он из проверки выводит, будто я ввёл не то, что прописано в условии. Вот ОТРЫВОК кода:

```
want = input("Выберите знак действия для вашего примера (+, -, /, *): ")
    if want != "+" or "-" or "/" or "*":
        print("!!! | Вы должны ввести ЗНАК действия!")
    else:
```

Comment: Непустая строка считается True. Оператор `or` выдаёт True, если слева или справа есть True. Поэтому, когда вы пишете `чтототам or "-"`, всё выражение автоматически считается True (потому что справа строка, которая True) и условие срабатывает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо or должен стоять and. Иначе в любом случае выведет ошибку.

```
want = input("Выберите знак действия для вашего примера (+, -, /, *): ")
if ((want != "+") and (want != "-") and (want != "/") and (want != "*")):
    print("!!! | Вы должны ввести ЗНАК действия!")
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
if want not in ["+","-", "/","*"]:
    print("!!! | Вы должны ввести ЗНАК действия!")
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно почитать про приоритет операторов. В конструкции

```
if want != "+" or "-" or "/" or "*":
```

вы проверяете, что переменная `want` не равна "+" или строка "-" имеет истинное значение или строка "/" имеет истинное значение или строка "*" имеет истинное значение. Так как не пустая строка всегда имеет истинное значение, `if` всегда будет выполняться.